# creating a sublist of a list under some condition C#

Tags: c#, list

I want to create a sublist of a list under some condition, but do not know how. Here is an Example:

suppose we have numbers from 1 to 5 and each number has a subarray/array.

```
1: 1 5 7 5 5 3 4 9
2: 0 1 2 3 4 6 3 4
3: 9 4 6 7 0 0 3 1
4: 4 6 3 7 8 0 0 1
5: 8 0 3 1 0 2 4 6
```

The numbers that come after `:` I will save in an array to get access fast.

Now I want to first creat a list of size 5 (numbers 1 to 5) and a sublist for each number under this condition:

```
if(list[i] > (arr1[j] + 1))
{
   //then save it in a sublist of the index i
}
```

My desired output would be like this:

```
List
    [1]
       [5]
       [7]
       [5]
       [5]
       [2]
       [4]
       [9]
    [2]
       [4]
       [6]
       [4]
    .
    .
    .
    [5]
       [8]
```

I could creat the first list by

```
List<int> List1 = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    List1.Add(i);
}
```

but how could I creat the sublist?

**Update:** I tried

```
List<Tuple <int,int>> List1 = new List<Tuple <int,int>>();
```

but it could not help.

Comment: _"I could creat the first list by...."_ No, because `List1.Add(j)` doesn't compile. The loop variable is `i` not `j`. The question is not really clear, at least not for me.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I correcte. it was a typo in index ;)

Comment: I think he wants to filter out numbers that are smaller than the index at which they are placed

Comment: Why answer for 2nd line is `4 6 4`, not `3 4 6 3 4`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko probably typo

Comment: @DmitryBychenko The Condition is `if th numbers is greater than (2+1)` which means all numbers greater than 3.

Comment: @Saber: in that case why the *last line* is `8 6` not just `8`? `(5 + 1 == 6)` and so `6` should not appear

Comment: @DmitryBychenko sorry you are right. I edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

```
List<Tuple <int,List<int>>> list = new List<Tuple <int,List<int>>>();

//populate the list 

if(list[i].Item1 > (arr1[j] + 1))
{
    list[i].Item2.Add(arr1[j]); 
}
```

From what I understand the input is this

```
1: 1 5 7 5 5 3 4 9
2: 0 1 2 3 4 6 3 4
3: 9 4 6 7 0 0 3 1
4: 4 6 3 7 8 0 0 1
5: 8 0 3 1 0 2 4 6
```

And the output should be this:

```
1: 5 7 5 5 3 4 9
2: 4 6 4
3: 9 6 7
4: 6 7 8
5: 8
```

So based on the index items that are smaller or equal to index should be left out

Comment: Can you tell me what OP's trying and why it didn't work?

Comment: He is trying to add a list to a specific index

Comment: @TimSchmelter updated answer so you better understand the question

Comment: Is it work when `if` condition is changed and then I have completely different condition that is not related to `List`? I mean let's I have something else in `If` and then I use only `list[i].Item2.Add(**); `

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do

Comment: well, if instead of `if(list[i].Item1 > (arr1[j] + 1)` I have another condition that does not consider/relate my defined list `list`. E.G. something like `string str; if(str.Equals("hello"))`.

Comment: you can change it the way you want based on what you need

Comment: @csharpwinphonexaml ,  I have one question regrad this method. I mean let's list from begining is empty and inside for loop I will add new members, will this method work?

Answer (score 1):

You can try *Linq*:

```
  List<int[]> source = new List<int[]>() {
    new int[] { 1, 5, 7, 5, 5, 3, 4, 9},
    new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 3, 4},
    new int[] {9, 4, 6, 7, 0, 0, 3, 1},
    new int[] {4, 6, 3, 7, 8, 0, 0, 1},
    new int[] {8, 0, 3, 1, 0, 2, 4, 6},
  };

  var result = source
    .Select((array, index) => array
      .Where(item => item > index + 2) // +2 since index is zero-based
      .ToArray()); // ToArray is not necessary here, but convenient for further work

  // Test

  String report = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    result.Select(item => String.Join(", ", item)));

  Console.Write(report);
```

Output is

```
   5, 7, 5, 5, 3, 4, 9
   4, 6, 4
   9, 6, 7
   6, 7, 8
   8
```

**Edit**: for *arbitrary* index numbers, I suggest using *dictionary* with key used as index:

```
  Dictionary<int, int[]> source = new Dictionary<int, int[]>() {
    {1, new int[] { 1, 5, 7, 5, 5, 3, 4, 9}},
    {2, new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 3, 4}},
    {3, new int[] { 9, 4, 6, 7, 0, 0, 3, 1}},
    {4, new int[] { 4, 6, 3, 7, 8, 0, 0, 1}},
    {5, new int[] { 8, 0, 3, 1, 0, 2, 4, 6}},
  };

  var result = source
    .Select(pair => pair.Value
       .Where(item => item > pair.Key + 1)
       .ToArray());
```

Comment: What if the index numbers are not in order?

Comment: @csharpwinphonexam: if index number are, in fact, *arbitrary* numbers then I suggest using `Dictionary<int, int[]>` where *key* is *index*

Comment: That's what I've been thinking - List<tuple<int,<list<int>>> seemed way too complex for the requirement.